# Windows firewall and network connections

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-firewall

I am disabling firewall for private network connection, but firewall still working on it. What else should I do to disable firewall on private network connection?

[image: Protected network connections]

Answer (score 0):

The dialog you have taken a screenshot of is for the *Public Profile*.  Try changing the same setting for the other profiles as well.  It is likely that you are not currently configured to use the Public profile.

Comment: I did it for all profiles and windows currently on Public profile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was to change the setting on **Inbound connections**.

You can choose between **Block (default)** and **Block all connections**.

If you select **Block all connections** the **Protected network connections** setting gets also ignored not only the rules.